# How do I implement a simple scheduler to start docker container on the least busy host

Tags: node.js, docker, scheduler

I am not using docker swarm or kubernetes. I need to implement a simple scheduler to start docker container on demand on the least busy host. The docker container runs nodejs codes BTW.

Is there any open source project out here already implements this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [kubernetes jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) if you need to run container once and on demand.
As for least busy node you can use [nodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature) to specify nodes where you don't have other apps or better to specify app [resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container) and allow kubernetes to decide where to run your app.